# MySQL data field to oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, date, datetime

I am using sqlldr to load mysql data in an Oracle database...  My problem is I have a DATE column in MySQL that Oracle doesn't like...

Here is the structure of my column in mysql:

```
Extra   Type    Field   Default Null    Key
        date    dateToSend      0000-00-00      NO
```

here is the entry in my ctl file:

```
DATETOSEND "CASE :DATETOSEND WHEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ELSE TO_DATE(:DATETOSEND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') END"
```

the oracle column I am using for "`DATETOSEND`" is  DATE

an example of the date field from mysql is: "`2014-08-14`"

and finally, the error I am getting from sqlldr is:

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

I know it's probably something with how I'm formatting the "TO_DATE" but I'm not sure what I'm missing....

UPDATE: This got it working:

```
DATETOSEND "to_date(SUBSTR(:DATETOSEND,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')"
```

Comment: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is an invalid date and can never be imported into Oracle

Comment: Yep, got it.  I tried this:   DATETOSEND "to_date(SUBSTR(:DATETOSEND,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is:

```
 CASE :DATETOSEND WHEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

The constant is an invalid date in Oracle.  Perhaps this will work:

```
 CASE TO_CHAR(:DATETOSEND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') WHEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I modified my sqlldr statment to:  DATETOSEND "CASE TO_CHAR(:DATETOSEND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') WHEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ELSE TO_DATE(:DATETOSEND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') END"

and got a new error: "Invalid Number"

Answer (score 0):

This got it working:

```
DATETOSEND "to_date(SUBSTR(:DATETOSEND,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')"
```